# AVAudioPlayer crashes on play

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

Working on audio first time. May be i am missing something please guide

I have added AVFoundation framework. added #import

and added this in viewDidLoad.

```
NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString* audioPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"001.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:audioPath];

if (!fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"Audio File not exist!");
}else{

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    self.audioPlayer = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];

    // It crashes at this line
    self.audioPlayer = [self.audioPlayer initWithData:audioData error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.audioPlayer);



}
```

Comment: Crashes with what message?

Comment: only prints this in output (lldb)

Answer (score 3):

I was using generic Breakpoint for any exception. Player was making crash because of this break point with no details. Just removed that breakpoint and now worked fine. Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

try this out this worked for me. also check for the audio file is played or not.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/001.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog([error description]);             
    else 
        [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: i tried your solution but still crashes when reached at line where it tries to play.

Comment: Yes i check same file in sample project.

Comment: yes its playing in my bundle. but not when i access using AVAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have to make strong property for `AVAudioPlayer` Instance. Either make it a global or make strong property.

```
//Global iVAR

AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
```

OR

```
//Property

@property(strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
```

then you should be able to play audio.